# Jenkins string parameters not accessible in ssh shell for remote host

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have passed `USERNAME` as string parameter in jenkins build.

I can access this on execute shell just fine using `$USERNAME` in jenkins but if I try to access them on shell for remote host, they aren't accessible. How do I pass them to `execute shell on remote host`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to send the variable as a parameter in your remote script. For example, if variable is $USERNAME.

```
ssh servername '/remote/script/file $USERNAME'
```

You can access this parameter by using parameter variables in the remote script ($1,$2...)

Comment: But I do not see the option in the shell to pass parameters